# Бегущая строка на CSS но вместо текста картинка

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, мне нужно сделать что то на подобии бегущей строки на CSS
Но вместо текста будет картинка
мне нужно вращать эту картинку в права на лево без каких либо пробелов
Грубо говоря заРепитить ее, пытался сделать таким образом, но есть большой пробел справа

HTML

```
<div class="scroll_bg" id="scroll_bg">
<img src="../img/jpg/slide_0.png">
<img src="../img/jpg/image.jpg">
</div>
```

SASS

```
@keyframes scroll
    0%
        transform: translate(0, 0)
    
    100%
        transform: translate(-100%, 0)

.scroll_bg
    display: block
    width: 100%
    white-space: nowrap
    overflow: hidden
    
    img
        display: inline-block
        padding-left: 100%
        -webkit-animation: scroll 5s infinite linear
        -moz-animation: scroll 5s infinite linear
        animation: scroll 5s infinite linear
```

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем через css - то можно вот так вот.

```css
@keyframes scroll{
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
.scroll_bg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: scroll 5s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: scroll 5s infinite linear;
  animation: scroll 5s infinite linear;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg/220px-Hopetoun_falls.jpg);
  width: 220px;
  height: 147px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll_bg" id="scroll_bg">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ня =)

```html
<marquee><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg/220px-Hopetoun_falls.jpg"></marquee>
```

Comment: Тег объявлен как deprecated, значит, браузеры могут убрать его поддержку в любой момент, и вся функциональность пропадёт

Comment: Ага. Это я добавил больше хохмы ради - чтобы показать, что иногда лучшее - враг хорошего...